# compile ObjectBox without examples

Tags: objectbox

I'm looking to compile ObjectBox without including the examples and test apps. Essentially, I want to keep only the ObjectBox library in my environment. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this?

It would be great if you could consider adding an option to remove examples when using the FetchContent_MakeAvailable command. This way, users would have the flexibility to exclude example programs from the build process, reducing unnecessary build time and keeping the project clean and concise

Comment: You may be able to do this using the SOURCE_SUBDIR as described on https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html (see https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/4757 which implemented it). In any case, you should probably create an issue at https://github.com/objectbox/objectbox-c/issues about this.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Uwe-ObjectBox , i have created an issue.